# Should I block this Ip range?

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler, robots.txt

There is a crawler on my site that does not identify as a robot in it's user agent.

one of the ip addresses is:
131.161.8.197

All of the bots belong in the Ip range of 131.161.

Apparently it is a "brasil baidu" based on an ipwhois.

Should I just go ahead and block that entire range of ips?

Comment: Yes you can block it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's originating from Brasil, the question really is.. do you need to target the Brasil area?

Blocking the crawler will mean that you have less traffic to deal with, so I personally would say yes to blocking it.

You can either use your robots.txt or do it via server side. Obviously you can use the:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 131.161.8.197
```

or:

```
User-agent: Baiduspider
User-agent: Baiduspider-video
User-agent: Baiduspider-image
Disallow: /
```